# How to efficiently access the first and last occurance index that meet a condition in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, indexing

The idea is to access the first and last occurrence index that meet a condition in Pandas.

The following code can achieve the said objective. But, Im just curios whether there is more efficient way to achieve the same result

From the example and code, it is expected to get the second and fifth row as the final result.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A':[1,2,3,4,5,10,2],
               'B' :[1,2,3,4,5,110,2]})

IndexGreaterThan=df[df['A'].gt(2)].index.tolist() 

Voltage_FirstAboveThrshold=df.at[IndexGreaterThan[0],'A']
Time_FirstAboveThrshold=df.at[IndexGreaterThan[0],'B']

Voltage_LastAboveThrshold=df.at[IndexGreaterThan[-1],'A']
Time_LastAboveThrshold=df.at[IndexGreaterThan[-1],'B']
```

Then

```
print(Voltage_FirstAboveThrshold,Time_FirstAboveThrshold)
print(Voltage_LastAboveThrshold,Time_LastAboveThrshold)
```

Output

```
3 3
10 110
```

Appreciate for any suggestion

Comment: Maybe [last_valid_index](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23.4/generated/pandas.DataFrame.last_valid_index.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

- [`.iloc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html) - Purely integer-location based indexing for selection by position.

---

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'A':[1,2,3,4,5,10,2],
               'B' :[1,2,3,4,5,110,2]})

df = df[df['A'].gt(2)]
df2 = df.iloc[[0, -1]]
print(df2)

    A    B
2   3    3
5  10  110
```

Comment: Thanks for the fast response and clean alternative, appreciate it

Comment: 'df[df['A'].gt(2)].iloc[[0, -1]]'  in one line

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
df[df.A.gt(2)].iloc[[0,-1]]
```

Details:

- `df[df.A.gt(2)]` selects rows with *A > 2*.
- `.iloc[[0,-1]]` selects first and last row (from the selected above).

Comment: Thanks for the fast response and great answer, pythonic,all in 1 line. But, I got an error. Not sure where I do wrong

Comment: df[df[''A'].gt(2)].iloc[[0,-1]], this help solve the problem

Comment: Your version of code is also OK, but I tried my version and it also works. Maybe you have some older version of *Pandas*, which does not allow the "attribute access" to columns (as I did)?

Comment: Yes, that might be the reason. May I know what version do you use? Seem the version you use can make the code more compact (i.e., omitting the '' when access by column label)

Comment: I use Python 3.7 and Pandas 0.25 (upgraded not long ago).